# Casbah Scala MongoDB driver - embedded objects

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I know that objects in MongoDB can contain multiple levels of data (just the way JSON objects can). However, the Casbah driver tutorial only covers the creation of "flat" objects, where there is just one level of data. How can I create and work with multilevel objects with Casbah?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its pretty intuitive.

construction:

```
val a: MongoDBOBject = DBObject("a" -> DBObject("b" -> "c"))
// results in { "a" : { "b" : "c"}}
```

access to inner fields [with dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
val c = a.expand[String]("a.b")
```

retrieval of inner object as DBObject, so you can make the same operations with it as with parent object:

```
val b = a.as[DBObject]("a")
```

Comment: Note: for this to work, remember to import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject, com.mongodb.casbah.commons.BaseImports._, com.mongodb.casbah.Implicits._, and com.mongodb.DBObject.

Comment: I think you can `import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.Imports._`. This will import DBObject, MongoDBObject and implicit conversion functions. I read that somewhere in the casbah docs.

Comment: How do you get the `.as[]` to work? I need `.asInstanceOf[]`. Is it the same thing?

Comment: @akauppi it's a method defined for MongoDBObject. [As you can see from the doc](http://take.ms/BdeiE), it works like `apply() + asInstanceOf[]`

Comment: @om-nom-nom Ah, of course! Hadn't realized it came from the MongoDBObject API. (oh btw, you might want to decapitalize one B? DBOB)